# update array of objects based on inputs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, arrays, object

I have an array of objects at the front end. Here is the content of it.

```
0: Object
 Name: Ria
 Age: 27
 Sex: Female

1: Object
 Name: Brian
 Age: 23
 Sex: Male

2: Object
 Name: Rick
 Age: 32
 Sex: Male
```

I update this to a table. I am trying to add 2 functions here.

If user clicks on 'Add button', it should create a new object with empty parameters. Something like this.

```
0: Object
 Name: 
 Age: 
 Sex: 

1: Object
 Name: Ria
 Age: 27
 Sex: Female

2: Object
 Name: Brian
 Age: 23
 Sex: Male

3: Object
 Name: Rick
 Age: 32
 Sex: Male
```

Similarly, if a user clicks delete button, i will pass the selected values which the user wants to delete. Suppose they are

```
Brian,Rick
```

We will know that due to these names, object 1 and 2 needs to be deleted. so the new object array should be like this.

```
 0: Object
 Name: Ria
 Age: 27
 Sex: Female
```

Objects 1 and 2 wont be there since passed parameters indicated that they needs to be removed from the list. I want this to be dynamic. Depending on the parameters passed, the object array should be updated.

Comment: Have you tried anything? What were the issues? Could you post a code sample?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To insert at the begining of the array use `unshift`

```
array.unshift({
    Name: null,
    Age: null,
    Sex: null
});
```

to remove you can use `filter`

```
function remove(names) {
    array = array.filter(function(obj) {
        return names.indexOf(obj.Name) == -1;
    });
}
remove(['Brian', 'Rick']);
```

or if you want to pass string use:

```
function remove(names) {
    names = names.split(',');
    array = array.filter(function(obj) {
        return names.indexOf(obj.Name) == -1;
    });
}
remove('Brian,Rick');
```

Comment: @jcubic- so uunshift will shift all the objects by 1 place and insert new row of null values at 0th element ?

Comment: @Neeva yes, it will insert at 0 index whatever you're passing to it.

Comment: @jubic- how cool is that. thanks for your answer.

Comment: @Neeva don't forget to mark the anwer it that solve your problem.